# Log disks spin up and spin down

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, logging

I have a file / media server running on Ubuntu 18.04. It has 1 SSD on which Ubuntu is installed and 4 HDD's for various files.
I found some information on how to log the disks activities and that seems straight forward enough (like iotop). However, I would like to log the following as well and can't find how to do that:

- Exact time when a disk spins up
- What process/activity is responsible for that to disk spin up
- Exact time when a disk spins down again

Anyone know a (simple) way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>For recording spin up & spin down, hd-idle should be enough: https://github.com/adelolmo/hd-idle</strike> hd-idle will only log the spin up/down triggered by itself. I've made a script to monitor this:

```
import subprocess
import time
import re
from pathlib import Path
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',)
logger = logging.getLogger('hd-spin-log')

DISK_BLACKLIST = ['sda']

def get_all_disk_status():
    ret = {}
    for path in Path('/dev').glob('sd*'):
        if path.name[-1].isdigit():
            continue
        if path.name in DISK_BLACKLIST:
            continue
        try:
            statOut = subprocess.check_output(['hdparm', '-C', str(path)]).decode()
        except Exception:
            ret[path.name] = '(hdparm fail)'
            logger.warning('hdparm failed!', exc_info=True)
            return
        m = re.findall(r'(?m)drive state is:  (.*?)$', statOut)
        if m:
            ret[path.name] = m[0]
        else:
            ret[path.name] = '(unknown)'
            logger.warning("Failed to parse drive state for %s, output %s", path, statOut)
    return ret

def main():
    logger.info("monitor start")
    lastStat = get_all_disk_status()
    logger.debug("first time stat: %s", lastStat)
    while True:
        try:
            curStat = get_all_disk_status()
            logger.debug('cur stat: %s', curStat)
            if curStat != lastStat:
                # stat changed!
                disks = set(list(curStat.keys()) + list(lastStat.keys()))
                for d in disks:
                    if d in lastStat and d in curStat:
                        if lastStat[d] != curStat[d]:
                            logger.info('disk %s: %s -> %s', d, lastStat[d], curStat[d])
                    elif d in lastStat and d not in curStat:
                        logger.info('disk %s: %s -> [disappeared]', d, lastStat[d])
                    elif d not in lastStat and d in curStat:
                        logger.info('disk %s: [new] -> %s', d, curStat[d])
                    else:
                        assert False
            else:
                logger.debug('disk stat not changed...')
            lastStat = curStat
        except Exception:
            logger.warning("exception during check!", exc_info=True)
        time.sleep(10)

main()
```

Example log:

```
2023-05-17 23:09:39,866 hd-spin-log.py INFO monitor start
2023-05-17 23:09:59,916 hd-spin-log.py INFO disk sdc: unknown -> standby
```

For spin up culprits, fatrace may be a good choice.